# Unable to Install Alfresco package in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

hey i tried to install alfresco package on my ubuntu 20.04, but i was unable to install it.
please guide me with the steps and procedure to install. i Tried the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:guilhem-fr/swftools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install swftools
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libgif4
sudo apt-get -y install libart-2.0-2
sudo apt-get install ghostscript imagemagick
convert --version
wget http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/s/swftools/swftools_0.9.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
chmod a+x swftools_0.9.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i swftools_0.9.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get purge openoffice.org ure
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Please help me with the installation of Alfresco and guide me with the complete steps...

Comment: What are the exact commands and steps you have tried. What error messages did you get. You have given no info that can be used to help you, we can not guess what you did.

Comment: I don't know what the `alfresco` package is, and a quick search for it on Ubuntu repositories came up with no results, but from your commands I assume it relates to an extension for `libreoffice`, relates to graphics somehow, python, cannot co-exist with open office .. and a lot of stuff that makes no sense.  You provided no clear indication of what you want (where is it from?), how those commands relate? why you executed them to reach your goals, plus what errors or output you got from them (ie. wha you want us to help with).

Comment: https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-blog/installing-alfresco-6-community-edition-in-ubuntu-using-docker/ba-p/303840

Answer (score 0):

If you need to install Alfresco Community components, here is an entry point for documentation :
https://www.alfresco.com/thank-you/thank-you-downloading-alfresco-community-edition

I quote :

> **1. Containerized deployment (7.0 GA)**
>
> Recommended and fastest option
>
> The Alfresco Community Edition 7.0 GA is available for Docker and
> Kubernetes. This is our recommended option for all technical
> personnel. Containerized deployment allows for fast, standardized
> deployments—perfect for a trial or PoC.
>
> ...
>
> **2. Non-containerized deployment using Ansible**
>
> Detailed option for experienced technical admins
>
> The Alfresco Community Edition 7.0 supports Ansible playbooks to
> simplify the deployment for organizations that prefer
> non-containerized environments.
>
> ...
>
> **3. Non-containerized manual deployment**
>
> Manual deployment for advanced customization
>
> The Alfresco Community Edition can be deployed manually in cases where
> advanced customization is required. This method requires more time,
> and is recommended only for experienced database and application
> server administrators.

There is a video to explain the first method (using docker containers). And links to the instructions for the others methods relying on Ansible or a zip download :

- https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/community/install/containers/
- https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/community/install/ansible/
- https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/community/install/zip/

Does that help ?